# Pass touch event from recycler to its parent LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, animation, android-recyclerview

I have something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="cntxt">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Title -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

        <!-- Recycler -->
        <CustomRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/main_activity_rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:scrollingCache="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When the layout is scrolled to top, when the user makes a similar to "swipe to refresh" move with his finger, I need to make a translate animation on Y axes. In other words, I need to follow the move of the finger the whole recycler if the recycler is on top.

I tried to attach an onTouch listener to the recycler but the inner scroll of the recycler makes the situation unclear. 
Any ideas to achieve this animation?

If I attach the onTouchListener to the main_layout and do the fling from the iner textview, the animation plays normally. But when I touch the recycler nothing happens (except of recycler's inner scrolls)
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make the outer most layer a

```
SwipeRefreshLayout
```

Instead of a relative layout. This will give you the pull to refresh functionality any way.

Also note, under the swipe layout mentioned, there can only be one direct child view so what ever you put... Make sure to put it in the linear layout you have.

You can attach an OnRefreshListener to listen to the pull of the refresh layout.

Comment: You'll get the default round animation and it can't be changed though. Maybe if you want another animation, you can follow the code of the layout and create your own view with your own animation set

Comment: the problem is the scroll listener of the recycler. Is there any way to by pass it in one case like "is at top"?

Comment: Not sure about the the scroll listener, but the method i have suggested no longer needs you to have a scroll listener for your recycler view. The refresh layout takes care of the fact that your recycler view Scrolls up and down and only refreshes when it's fully at top